# Group By in Hive on partitioned table gives duplicate result rows

Tags: hadoop, group-by, hive, hiveql

Using release 0.11.0. I get incorrect results when trying to execute this query

```
select t1.symbol, max(t1.maxts - t1.orderts) as diff from 
    (select catid, symbol, max(cast(timestamp as double)*1000) as maxts, min(cast(timestamp as double)*1000) as orderts, count(*) as cnt 
        from cat where recordtype in (0,1) and customerid=srcrepid group by symbol, catid) t1
where t1.cnt > 1
group by t1.symbol;
```

As you can see, there is a subquery with a group by statement. This subquery calculates the maximum and minimum of a timestamp value per MYID and SYMBOL.

Now, I have 24 symbols. In the outer query, I want to find the max difference per SYMBOL and so I group by SYMBOL.

The problem is that this returns 864 result rows right now. Hive seems to fail to reduce the last result into what I would expect to see.

Is this a bug? Can anyone reproduce this? I have 6 nodes running with 4 symbols per node.

Table used:

```
create table cat(CATID bigint, CUSTOMERID int, FILLPRICE double, FILLSIZE int, INSTRUMENTTYPE int, ORDERACTION int, ORDERSTATUS int, ORDERTYPE int, ORDID string, PRICE double, RECORDTYPE int, SIZE int, SRCORDID string, SRCREPID int, TIMESTAMP timestamp) PARTITIONED BY (SYMBOL string, REPID int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as ORC;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;
```

Edited: Edited because the query was inconsistent with the actual table used, making it hard to provide any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Yin on the hive [mail list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201309.mbox/%3CCAOSFW12WV-Yo+sVUVN1s+JkB9FMOvxcp=2TPjpDsizLoWUuQag@mail.gmail.com%3E) this is a bug related to this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5149).

When Hive only uses a single mapreduce job, both partitioning columns are used whereas my query would only like to group by symbol.

Evidently this bug has been fixed in trunk.

And here's another [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5237) that demonstrates the problem more clearly

Answer (score 0):

I think it might work if, in the outer query, you structure it thisaway:

SELECT t1.symbol, max(t1.maxts) - min(t1.orderts) AS diff, ....

Comment: I will try this when I have machines available. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that if you introduce an ORDER BY clause it after the first GROUP BY forces hive into two MR jobs and there by gives the correct results.

As requested adding the query modification as an example.

select t1.symbol, max(t1.maxts - t1.orderts) as diff from 
    (select catid, symbol, max(cast(timestamp as double)*1000) as maxts, min(cast(timestamp as double)*1000) as orderts, count(*) as cnt 
        from cat where recordtype in (0,1) and customerid=srcrepid group by symbol, catid **ORDER BY symbol, catid**) t1
where t1.cnt > 1
group by t1.symbol;

But yes this is still only a work around the issue, but the real problem is Hive uses the wrong partitioning fields in that query, it should have just used symbol but if you see the explain on that it uses both symbol and catid which causes it to give multiple results.

Adding the ORDER BY forces Hive to do the second group by in a different MR job giving us the right results.

Comment: Sounds like this could be a good answer, can you please edit and show more details that will help answer the Q directly?